# Separate local search from Cortana in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Is it possible to use Cortana + Web search separately from local search in Windows 10? Often I know I'm looking for a local file and I don't want this query to be recorded.

To get Cortana to search locally I have to click "My Stuff" but this is only an option after the query has been entered. I tried to "outwit" it by entering a false query, clicking My Stuff, then editing the query, but the new query is still routed through Cortana. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Obviously not a duplicate; I'm not talking about multiple users. I just want a separate search bar, or a toggle.

Comment: If you're looking for files specifically, perhaps just open Explorer and use the Search bar in there.

Comment: @Ramhound: There are two answers, neither of which answers my question. There is no "Search online and include web results" option if Cortana is enabled. Your related question also isn't.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Getting that "Quick access" bar in the task bar would be ideal. This is how previous versions of Windows used to behave. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Press the Windows key in Windows 8 and type a query. It will search locally. Press it in Windows 10 and type a query. It will search globally. To replicate the Windows 8 behavior in Windows 10 you have to use Quick access, which is nothing but local search.